# How to solve a Capybara::ElementNotFound Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm stuck with the following problem, this is the first time I use capybara, have you an idea how I can solve this issue, thanks

I use rails 3.0.0 and the following gems

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'cucumber-rails'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'spork'
gem 'launchy'
```

I have the following in my senario

```
When I go to the new customer page
And I fill in "Email" with "john@example.com"
```

in my customer_steps.rb I have

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2|
  fill_in arg1, :with => arg2
end
```

In my view

```
- form_for @customer do |f|
  = f.label :email, 'Email'
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.submit
```

When I run my scenario I get this error message

```
 Scenario: Register new customer                  # features/manage_customers.feature:7
    When I go to the new customer page             # features/step_definitions/customer_steps.rb:1
    And I fill in "Email" with "john@example.com"  # features/step_definitions/customer_steps.rb:5
      cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Email' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/customer_steps.rb:6:in `/^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/manage_customers.feature:9:in `And I fill in "Email" with "john@example.com"'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake!!!

```
When I go to the new customer page
```

before the step was

```
When /^I go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  path_to page_name 
end
```

I forgot the visit...

```
When /^I go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name) 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this id of the field instead, which should be like

> And I fill in "customer_email" with "john@example.com"

if the @customer is a object customer model

Comment: thanks Rishav for your answer, I already tried that and got the same error, is there a way to 'dump' the html of the page to see if capybara search in the right code?

Comment: well, when I run cucumber i have nothing in my log files (dev or test)

Comment: puts page.body is how you get the output at the current step