# Capybara Not Finding Form Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

I was trying Capybara for the first time and having trouble with it finding my form. I'm using Rspec, Capybara, Rails 3.2.8, and Twitter Bootstrap.

In my test, I had:

```
before do
  choose  "Residential"
  choose  "Storage"
  fill_in "Customer Location",  with: 30082
  fill_in "datepicker",         with: 2012-12-02
  fill_in "Email",              with: "jesse@test.com"
  fill_in "Phone",              with: "555-555-5555"
 end
```

And was getting the error:

```
Failure/Error: choose  "Residential"
   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
     cannot choose field, no radio button with id, name, or label 'Residential' found
```

In my form, I had (excerpt):

```
    <%= quote.radio_button :customer_type, "Residential"%>
    <%= quote.label "Residential", class:"radio inline" %>
```

When I fired up the server, I could see the form and Firebug showed that I had a label named "Residential" associated with the form element.

After searching for the problem and finding this post: [Capybara not finding form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356161/capybara-not-finding-form-elements/13165829#13165829) (among others), I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately went back to Capybara's Rubydocs (  http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions ) and found the section on the "Choose" method.

I didn't dive deep into the documentation, but I saw that it was looking for a "locator" in the :radio_button and so tried associating one directly.

I thus changed my form to (notice I added "id" to the form element):

```
    <%= quote.radio_button :customer_type, "Residential", id:"Residential"%>
    <%= quote.label "Residential", class:"radio inline" %>
```

and that portion of the test passed! I repeated with each of my form elements and everything performed as expected.

Hope this is useful to someone else.