# Unable to find field "Content" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automation, cucumber, bdd

This is my Write_blog.feature file

```
Feature: Write blog
As a Blog Owner
I can write new blog post
Scenario: Write Blog
Given I am on the Blog Homepage
When I click on the "New Post" Link
And I fill "My first blog" as Title
And I fill "Test content" as content
And I click on "Post" button 
Then I should see the blog i just posted
```

This is my write_blog_steps.feature steps

```
Given(/^I am on the Blog Page$/) do
  visit ("/posts")
end

When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" Link$/) do |arg1|
  click_on "New Post"
end

When(/^I fill "([^"]*)" as title$/) do |title|
  @title = title
  fill_in  "Title", :with => title 
end

When(/^I fill "([^"]*)" as content$/) do |content|
  fill_in "Content", :with => content
end

When(/^I click on "([^"]*)" button$/) do |btn|
  click_button  btn
end

Then(/^I should see the blog i just posted$/) do
  page_should have_content(@title)
end
```

And When i try to run it with : #cucumber features/write_steps.feature
This is the following error

And I fill "Content" as content     features/step_definitions/write_post_steps.rb:14
      Unable to find field "content" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/write_post_steps.rb:15:in `/^I fill "([^"]*)" as content$/'
      features/write_post.feature:8:in`And I fill "Test Content" as content'
What is the mistake here ?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072095/how-does-fill-in-work-in-rspec-capybara?

Comment: ok, so one of your tests is failing. Do you understand what this test is doing? It's appears to be doing some front-end automation (visiting website, parsing the HTML and checking for some string). To see your template and generated HTML would be necessary to answer this question (i.e. look at the page source after you visit the page in the browser)