# Unable to find field (Capybara::ElementNotFound) on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm starting with cucumber and i'm trying to make a test that create a new movie in my rails. So in my teste1.feature

```
Feature: É possivel acessar a pagina de Novo Filme



Scenario: É possivel visitar paginas
  Given I visit "/articles"
  And I press the "Novo Filme" button
  Then I should see the "/articles/new" page



Scenario: Add a movie

  Given I visit "/articles"
  And I press the "Novo Filme" button
  Then I should see the "/articles/new" page
  Given I am on a new movies page
  When I fill in "article_title" with "Sta Uors"
  And I fill in "f.number_field" with "10.5"
  And I press "Salvar Novo Filme"
  Then I should see "/articles"
  Then I should see the "Sta Uors" at "tabelafilme"
```

and in my teste1.step i have

```
#Given(/^I visit "([^"]*)"$/) do 


# visit article_path # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
#end
Given (/^I visit "(.*)"/) do |place|
 visit place
end

And(/^I press the "([^"]*)" button$/) do |arg|
  click_on( arg ) # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end


Then(/^I should see the "([^"]*)" page$/) do |place|
  visit "/articles/new"
end




Given (/^I am on a new movies page/) do
    visit "/articles/new"
end

When (/^I fill in "(.*)" with "(.*)"/) do |field , content|
 fill_in (field), :with => (content), visible: false
end

And(/^I press "([^\"]*)"/) do |button|
    click_button(button)
end

Then (/^I should see "([^\"]*)"/) do |arg|
    page.find_by_id('notice').text == arg
end

Then (/^I should see the "([^\"]*)" at "([^\"]*)"/) do |film, table|
    expect(page).to have_css("#tebelafilme", :text => table)
    find('td', text: film)
end
```

but i'm still getting this error

```
When I fill in "article_Titulo" with "Sta Uors"   # features/step_definitions/teste1.rb:24
  Unable to find field "article_Titulo" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/step_definitions/teste1.rb:25:in `/^I fill in "(.*)" with "(.*)"/'
  features/teste1.feature:18:in `When I fill in "article_Titulo" with "Sta Uors"'
```

So, i go to the project runing and click on my article_title to inspect on html page what's the name to put on cucumber, and the id name is "article_text", the label is "article_Titulo", and cucumber cannot find the field. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

First as far as [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method) for fill_in goes it looks like its expecting a string specifically for both of those arguments. You could try doing `fill_in "#{field}", :with => "#{content}", visible: false` to leave no doubt that you're feeding it strings.

However if you are creating the field with the `text_field` helper method, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837039/5451051) should do it. Looks like the elements created with an underscore in the name have that underscore stripped by the time it gets to the DOM.